# Double regex search loop makes problems

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, loops

I'm writing a code to send a values (one by one) to `send` function which will send it as msg to me. I have a two lists `allowed` and `denied` for regex `keywords` which are allowed in `re.search` and which are denied. I'm **scraping** an elements from web, trying to filter it with `re.search allowed` which works, and send it to the `second function` where I'm trying to filter it second time. This time filter out string which contains `denied` words. Here Is the problem. When I'm doing a loop one time `allowed` it goes good, but when I'm trying to do the second loop for `denied` in loop, it sending the string two times to my `send` function. How could I change the code, to make it work please?

Here Is the code

```py
allowed = ["pc", "FUJITSU", "LIFEBOOK", "win" "Windows",
            "PC", "Linux" "linux", "HP", "hp", "notebook", "desktop",
            "raspberry", "NEC", "mac", "Mac", "Core"]
denied = ["philips", "samsung"]
used = set()


source = requests.get("https://jmty.jp/aichi/sale-pcp").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')


def skype_login(user, password):
    sk = Skype(user, password)
    return(sk)


def send(sk, title, address, price, town, topic='Not'):
    for c in sk.chats.recent():
        chat = sk.chats[c]
        if hasattr(chat, 'topic') and chat.topic == topic:
            chat.sendMsg(f'Some string {title} \n {price} \n \n {town} \n \n URL: {address}' )
            break
    sleep(1)
    chat.sendMsg("Additional Message")


def jimoti(sk):
    global used
    for h2 in soup.find_all('div', class_='p-item-content-info'):
        title = h2.select_one('.p-item-title').text
        address = h2.select_one('.p-item-title').a["href"]
        price = (h2.select_one('.p-item-most-important').text).replace("円", "").replace("\n", "").replace(",", "")
        price = int(price)
        town = h2.select_one('.p-item-supplementary-info').text
        if price < 2000 and title not in used:
            used.add(title)
            for pattern in allowed:
                print(pattern)
                if re.search(pattern, title):
                    second(sk, title, address, price, town)
                    break

def second(sk, title, address, price, town):
    sk = sk
    title = title
    address = address
    price = price
    town = town
    # for prh in denied:   # Here it makes the problem
    #     print(prh)
    #     if re.search(prh, title):
    #         break
    #     else:
    send(sk, title, address, price, town)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sk = skype_login('username', 'pass')
    while True:
        jimoti(sk)
        sleep(randint(11,20))
```

Comment: Have you traced through the code yourself in any way?

Comment: You already have a call such as `print(pattern)`.  Put similar statements in the various functions and loops to see what is being called twice.

Comment: @C Perkins I know that it is a loop in loop so it do two times, but I don't know how to make it without that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your code correctly you had this set up (pseudo-python):

```
for bad in denied:
    if bad exists in string:
        break
    else:
        send message
```

This means that for every denied word that **isn't** found, you send the message. So if there are two bad words and it doesn't contain either, then you'll send it twice.

You can easily fix this by just having a bool

```
def second(sk, title, address, price, town):
    # I'm not sure why you do this, it's 100% unnecessary
    # sk = sk
    # title = title
    # address = address
    # price = price
    # town = town
    is_ok = True
    for prh in denied:
         if re.search(prh, title):
             is_ok = False
             break
    if is_ok:
        send(sk, title, address, price, town)
```